# Unable to show hint when using textWebPassword in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Unable to show hint in edit text view when using `inputtype = textWebPassword` in layout.

Comment: Run your project on real device it's work perfectly

Comment: Yes now its working.... Thanks @MohammadAli

Comment: Welcome happy to help :) @Hkh

Answer (score 0):

Its working smoothly use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/et_web_pwd"
    android:inputType="textWebPassword"
    android:hint="Enter Web Password"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please this are both work for me

with TextInputLayout

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_FirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/label_first_name"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:inputType="textWebPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Text.Montserrat_Regular"
                android:textColor="@color/text_Regular"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Without Input layout

```
  <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_FirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/label_first_name"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:inputType="textWebPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Text.Montserrat_Regular"
                android:textColor="@color/text_Regular"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
```